# /usr/bin/mount: not found in a .sh script

Tags: bash, sh, shebang

The first line of my script is

```
/usr/bin/mount /dev/sdb4 /media/user/Data
```

Running it I get

```
/home/patrick/Scripts/DataBackup.sh: 1: /home/patrick/Scripts/DataBackup.sh: ﻿/usr/bin/mount: not found
```

Even if I put sudo before the mount command it does not find sudo neither.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Edit your Q to include the output of `uname -srv`. (Don't reply in comments please). Good luck.

Comment: Sounds like your editor is adding a byte order mark. Please ensure that your script does not have a BOM.

Comment: This does not look like an error by `bash`, but by `sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: using Libreoffice to write the script, bash gives a not found error on whatever was written on the first line.

Comment: Libreoffice might be adding a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file (which will confuse anything that expects plain text). [This superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/345814/exporting-utf-8-text-from-libreoffice-without-byte-order-mark) suggests there should be a checkbox in the Save As dialog to control this.

Answer (score 2):

Put this as your first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The existing lines will appear after the ['shebang' line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) above.

Comment: I get #!/bin/bash: not found, but mount is executed correctly. I am confused

Comment: How are you running this script? Exactly what do you type? Have you ever used bash before?